# Using Ajax to call Webservice

Tags: ajax, vb.net, web-services

The web service I am using is GeocodeFarm, and the API documentation says to send requests like this

```
http://www.geocodefarm.com/api/reverse/json/*api_key*/*latitude*/*longitude*/
```

it returns JSON output. I have a place on my page where people can type in their latitude and longitude and when they click submit I want it to reverse geocode using this URL and return the address. So I know I will need to parse the json when I get it back, but since it looks like it's not a .asmx I'm unfamilliar with how to do this. Could anyone help me understand the syntax of the Ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need a vb.net specific answer but you can use jQuery to make the AJAX request:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.geocodefarm.com/api/reverse/json/*api_key*/*latitude*/*longitude*/" + searchBox.value, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/#basic-overview-using-jquery-ui-on-a-web-page